# How to read data from wlan0 with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello I'm interested in reading data from my network card (eth0,wlna0).
Is there any library in python which can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are packages available such as pypcap, dpkt and scapy

pypcap example:

```
import pcap

pc = pcap.pcap('wlan0')
for ts, pkt in pc:
    print ts, repr(pkt)
```